# Continuous Integration for GWT

Tags: gwt, continuous-integration, bamboo

We are using GWT as our main front end technology.

We are using Bamboo as our Build Server & GIT as our source code management Tool.

Our application is very huge and divided into different modules. But still the compilation on local developer machine with 4 GB RAM takes lot of time.

Question is :

As part of Continuous Integration , Should we build the GWT code on local developer machine or not? If yes then what should be approach taken to fasten the build process ? What is the best practices for building GWT enterprise application for developers?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards , Niraj Salot

Answer (score 2):

1.- *Should we build the GWT code on local developer machine or not?*

Yes, Your project must be set up so as it is possible to build in any machine with a single order, I mean running `ant build`, `mvn package`, etc (depending on your build system). That guarantees that any developer can build and experiment with the project in her preferred OS, and CI system is able to test and build integration and production artifacts.

2.- *If yes then what should be approach taken to fasten the build process?*

You have to configure your environment so as only artifacts built by the CI server can go to production. Nothing especial but dictate some rules and conventions to your team, so as project builds do not depend on any particular IDE or OS configuration.

3.- *What is the best practices for building GWT enterprise application for developers?*

GWT is java, any generic practice you read for Java projects is applicable to GWT: stable build system, run quality code tools against your code, use CI for early realising defects, and a lot of TESTING.

4.- Other recommendations

Related with testing, since running tests for client code is slow, you should consider to use a MVP pattern, so almost the app code is in Model and Presenter classes and you can run those unit tests in the JVM. Then trust in well tested widgets to implement your views, hence you don't have to unit test them. If you create your own widgets consider using UIbinder to make compositions based on other widgets or just plain html. In the case of widgets with lots of java code you should test them using GWTTestCase. Your JVM tests should be very fast, so as developers run them in any interaction, GWTTestCases and integration tests can be run by CI.

You could consider to install a review code system like gerrit, IMO if you don't do pair-programing, code-reviewing is fundamental. With code review, you can test patches before they go to master.

Related with developer cycles, try to use super-dev-mode with gwt-2.7.0. Teach your developers how to debug client code in Chrome (it has full support for source maps), and tell them about debug limitations in other browsers so as they use other browsers only to check whether your app is working in all platforms. Discourage using classic dev-mode since it's being discontinued. You can experiment with the new [SDBG](http://goo.gl/37Jlyi) plugin to integrate super-dev-mode with eclipse debugger.

Comment: Thanks. So It would mean that developer should build the source code first on their local machine before pushing something on main repo from where the CI server would pick-up. But then the question comes how we can resolve the performance issue with GWT? I tried with GWT 2.6 and super dev mode but it was too slow.. Any suggestion here? is GWT 2.7 server dev mode is recommended to resolve the performance issue?

Comment: Yes, 2.7 is much faster. Re. building locally before pushing: it's a choice you have to make, but it ensures a cleaner commit history. If you can, plug-in your CI to build code-reviews (if you do reviews before commit/merge, which you should IMO) so devs can push to review / push to dedicated branch and the CI server builds it before the changes are merged to `master`/`trunk`. During that time, devs can start working on other tasks, and switch back to the previous one if the build fails (without impacting other devs as it's not merged yet). Nothing specific to GWT here actually.

Comment: What I mean is that developer should run all JVM test in her local, and it would guarantee that ~70-80% of app code works. But since most developers like to see the application in a browser, they can run it in superdev mode, as Thomas said it is really fast in 2.7, refreshing the UI should recompile big apps in less than a couple of seconds the first time it takes a while though. But they don't have to produce any war nor optimised JS in their local.